# webpack AngularCompilerPlugin hostReplacementPaths option does not work

Tags: angular, webpack, ngtools

After I've updated to Angular6 and updated `@ngtools/webpack` from "6.0.0-beta.8" to "6.1.2" I found that **hostReplacementPaths** option does not work anymore.

Normally it replaces correct env files:

```
new AngularCompilerPlugin({
  ...
  hostReplacementPaths: {
    'environments/environment.ts': environmentFiles[NODE_ENV]
  },
  ...
})
```

But now it does not.

I made deep debug into @ngtools/webpack and found that `normalize` function here 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/ngtools/webpack/src/virtual_file_system_decorator.ts#L188
does not work

this one 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular_devkit/core/src/virtual-fs/path.ts#L199

still could not find what went wrong with it.
maybe somebody already solved this issue?

Created an issue in angular-cli repo - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11801

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in your issue, this is a known bug with version `6.1.0-rc.2` and until a patch has been pushed out, you should downgrade back to `6.1.0-rc.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like will be fixed soon by this PR - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/11809

As James mentioned, there was a bug introduced in `6.1.0-rc.2` by this commit:  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/86a62adbe8faeb4628296d5d6915c54e6dbfd85b

Paths were not resolved properly.

Before:

```
const normalizedFrom = normalize(from);
const normalizedWith = normalize(this._options.hostReplacementPaths[from]);
```

Suggested fix:

```
const normalizedFrom = resolve(normalize(this._basePath), normalize(from));

const normalizedWith = resolve(
  normalize(this._basePath),
  normalize(this._options.hostReplacementPaths[from]),
);
```